# How to do look ups in android for example if i chose Audi car then i should get its variants and other details in android

Tags: java, android, arrays, list

I am making a simple premium calculator for motor insurance, where in i have to get info from user but the problem is i am not able to do look ups for example if i select a particular brand of car(Audi) from a spinner then the other spinner list should give that brands variants(A4,A6,A8...) and if i chose a particular variant in that then the CC Range of that car like wise, i tried using if and for loops but with the kind of car brands and variants its not possible, i am looking for a way were the first list value should be the key for second list value like wise, I'm building the app in android so please suggest me how to go further thank you.

Comment: Take a look at SQLite databases http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to create your object hierarchy with the lists inside. For example the Audi car object has a list of brand objects, and the brand objects have a list of CCrange objects etc.

Then have your first spinner populate based on your Car object names, and when selected, populate the next spinner by getting the list of brands from that car object.

Car object

- string Name
- ArrayList rangeList

Brand object

- string Name
- ArrayList rangeList